# BigCommerce category layout Display product details

Tags: bigcommerce

Can i display the product details on bigcommerce category page layout, when i over the product name?

Simply i need to display the product details, without to enter the product details page, and without open the quick view box.

There is a way to change the layout or just the design of the template.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your category layout is in Grid View. You need to change that to List View to display product details on the category pages.

Store Settings / Display / Category Settings / Category Display Mode